# Variation of the multiway partition

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, partitioning

I've been working on some project and stumbled upon an issue that is a variation of the multiway partition problem. We can state the problem as follows:

> Given a set **S** of **n** integers, and a set **K** of **k** sums, find  **k** subsets of **S** so that the i-th subset has the sum of the i-th element of  **K**.

This does not strictly require partitioning of the set **S**, as some elements may be left unused.

My naive attempt was to first iterate through the elements of **S** and form a single-element subset if that element matches some of the sums. Then I would sort the elements of  **S** in an ascending order and sum up the elements until they reach a given sum ( subset sum problem ). However, this fails often.

The solution need not be accurate. The nature of the problem allows the error for each sum to be as large as 10%. However, it has to be reasonably fast . To give some info about input data, **n** is expected to be of the order of millions, whilst **k** is expected to be between 1 and 10 thousand. The algorithm should run in the range of 10s of seconds ( it will be used on a web interface, and the user shouldn't wait longer than a minute or two ).

If I'm not wrong, this is an NP-complete problem, but I don't need an exact solution, just a rough approximation. Any help is appreciated, since I couldn't find anything close to that I need,except the multiway partition problem, which can't exactly be used here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I found this piece of code that does something very similar (it's for exact N sum of the set).

https://github.com/ephemerant/poe-vendor-optimizer/blob/master/functions.js

It's in javascript but can be adapted to other languages, I've changed it to java in my case. Just had to do a new ArrayList(_a) for the recursive call otherwise it would change the same List between different recursion.

This will only do 1 set of given N, you have to call it in a loop until it returns an empty List (meaning there is no exact N sum possible left)

```
function smallest(N, A) {
  var n = sum(A);  // Largest possible result
  var a = A;       // Largest possible array

  if (N <= 0 || n < N)  // Is it impossible?
    return [];

  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (n == N)  // Are we already perfect?
      return a;

    var x = A[i];  // Element in A

    var _a = A.slice(i + 1);  // Subarray to the right of x

    _a = smallest(N - x.quality, _a);  // Recurse
    _a.unshift(x);             // Add x to beginning

    var _n = sum(_a);  // Sum of the subarray

    if (_n < n && _n >= N) {  // Is this subarray better?
      n = _n;
      a = _a;
    }
  }
```

Here's my Java code:

```
private List<SkillGem> smallest(int N, List<SkillGem> A) {
    int n = A.stream().mapToInt(SkillGem::getQuality).sum(); // Largest possible result
    List<SkillGem> a = A; // Largest possible array
    if(N <= 0 || n < N) return new ArrayList<>(); // Is it impossible?

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        if (n == N)  // Are we already perfect?
            return a;
        if(i+1 > A.size()) return new ArrayList<>();

        SkillGem x = A.get(i); // Element in A
        List<SkillGem> _a = A.subList(i+1, A.size()); // Subarray to the right of x
        _a = smallest(N - x.getQuality(), new ArrayList<>(_a));  // Recurse
        _a.add(0, x); // Add x to beginning

        int _n = _a.stream().mapToInt(SkillGem::getQuality).sum();  // Sum of the subarray

        if (_n < n && _n >= N) {  // Is this subarray better?
            n = _n;
            a = _a;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```